# How Do You Create a New Directory with Terminal?

Tags: terminal

I'm using Terminal to upload some files from my mac and I was wondering if there is a way to create a new directory (folder) on the server. what is the command?

Answer (score 3):

Without knowing the protocol you use to connect to your server, it's hard to tell, but I'd suggest you try “mkdir”.